# VB.NET oMsg.Move(oProcessedFolder) Move Happens but is Not Removed rom Inbox

Tags: vb.net, move, outlook-2016

Wishing You are doing Great. This is my Logic

```
Create oForwardMessage from oMsg
Send oForwardMessage

oMsg.UnRead = False
**oMsg.Move(myDestFolderFolder)**
WriteToConsole(vbTab & vbTab & "Moved to Processed")
```

Happens rarely but .Move, the email is moved to the DestFolder, but not removed from the Inbox. Then I work with the Exchange team why this is happening. Then exchange is also researching.

So I put in some additional logic when reading the email if it's already Read, display a message and skip the email. Then by EOD I manually delete these unread messages as these emails are also available in the DestFolder.

After a day or two have this issue and then the process starts working the way it should be. I had the issue in Feb-2023 start for 2-3 days after that the emails are processing as if the issue never happened.

This process has been running for couple of years and have this hickup once a year.

What could cause this hickup in the .Move

Added some additional code to skip the Read emails.

Comment: The fact that whatever is happening resolves itself after some time would make me think the source problem may not be this code and could be Enviromental or user driven.